# Cannot set the location for java widget

Tags: java, swing

The problem is that I can't position the button where I want to. So I wrote this code to set again the location:

```
button.setLocation(new Point(100, 60));

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class gui {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        frame.add(panel);

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,25));
        button.setLocation(new Point(100, 60));
        panel.add(button);

        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,400));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("GUI App");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the method setBounds()! This method requires 4 parameters: The x & y coordinate and the width and height your button should have. Also you have to set the Layout to null... So try this:
`button.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 50) //just an example
frame.setLayout(null)`

Answer (score 0):

add below to your component:

```
  //JPanel layout
    panel.setLayout(null);
  // postioning
    button.setLocation(100,60);
```

As `panel.setLayout(null)` set your content panel to use absolute layout. Which you'd always have to set your component's bounds explicitly by using `setBounds` method.

Better to choose [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) the most suitable layout than using absolute layout.
ex:`panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.